# mxGraph codec.decode not adding cells to the actual graph

Tags: javascript, xml, mxgraph

I am trying to load and convert an XML file to a `mxGraph`, however when I call the codec it doesn't update my graph.

This is my function, where the container is the div where my graph will be located:

```
function loadXml(container, xml)
{
   // Checks if the browser is supported
   if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
   {
      // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
      mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
   }
   else
   {
     // Creates the graph inside the given container
     var graph = new mxGraph(container);

     // Adds rubberband selection to the graph
     new mxRubberband(graph);

     var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
     var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
     codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
   }
};
```

PS: I inspected the `doc.documentElement` and it seems correct.

Comment: i have the same problem :(

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue pop up due to mxGraph being imported with Webpack's exports-loader, but I believe it could happen in other circumstances.

The `mxCodec.prototype.decode(doc, graphModel)` function expects all mxGraph objects/constructors to be available in the global scope through the `window[objectName]` accessor.

If mxGraph is encapsulated within a module, the objects are not within global scope and the decoding fails.

To confirm that this is the issue, add a breakpoint in mxGraph's `mxCodec.prototype.decode` function and load your page. You can then validate whether the objects can be found or not.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I will give an answer for the community. You can parse the xml String using the `mxUtils.parseXml(xml)` function and get the cells out of it, then just import the cells into your `mxGraph` object, code shown below:

```
// Creates the graph inside the given container
var graph = new mxGraph(container);
let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
let cells = [];
while (elt != null)
{  
    let cell = codec.decode(elt)
    if(cell != undefined){
        if(cell.geometry != undefined){
            if(cell.id != undefined && cell.parent != undefined && (cell.id == cell.parent)){
                elt = elt.nextSibling;
                continue;
            }
            cells.push(cell);
        }
    }
    elt = elt.nextSibling;
}
graph.addCells(cells);
```

This should do the trick :)